# How to request parameter values from URL in PHP?

Tags: php

```
http://localhost/mysite/#id=98b7ee047f0a4fd6530d2538f7f929cc&com=289916
```

I need to get values of 'id' and 'com'. 
I have to put '#' symbol in front parameter, because I need the page without refreshing itself.

Comment: PHP can't do this as it it server-side only, and URL hashes are only client-side and are never sent to the server. You can however use JavaScript to get the hash and then send it to server via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$url = 'http://localhost/mysite/#id=98b7ee047f0a4fd6530d2538f7f929cc&com=289916';

echo "<pre>";
print_r(parse_url($url));
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => localhost
    [path] => /mysite/
    [fragment] => id=98b7ee047f0a4fd6530d2538f7f929cc&com=289916
)
```

Comment: seems good solution but how did you get the url?

Comment: This is for parsing a URL string, not for getting the current page's hash which is what I think the OP is wanting.

Comment: @crypticツ, @Deepu : I understood the problem, If you have control over generation of url, pass it as a query string, and if you really want a hash put it at the end of query string : something like this :`http://domain.com?q=querystring#hash`

Comment: @PrasanthBendra that won't work because if you want it to be sent to the server you would need to encode the `#` at which point it is no longer a hash and the browser will refresh the page when such a link is clicked.

Comment: @crypticツ : OK, then i guess he need to use javascript `window.location.hash` and to send it to server use AJAX

Comment: @crypticツ, @ PrasanthBendra: Yep, i'm gonna use Ajax. Thanks buddy

Answer (score -1):

For getting the url you can use

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

then you can apply the above method Quoted by Prasanth Bendra.

> echo ""; print_r(parse_url($url));

Comment: URL fragments (hashes) are not accessible server-side.

Comment: it's not possible through PHP. Ajax is the solution as @cryptic said.